# Encrypted or Password Protected Docker Container

Tags: docker, password, encryption, containers, rkt

I have some Docker containers. I want to login the containers with a password.

Is it possible?

If it is not possible then is there way to encrypt some folders in Docker?

I have tried `rkt` as well. I could not manage to enable the password protection for rkt containers, either.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/Senetas/crypto-cli. It allows you to encrypt/decrypt containers when pushing and pulling from a repo.
(Full disclosure I know the guy who wrote it)

Answer (score 2):

The [docker image specification](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/image/spec/v1.md) and the [OCI image specification](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec) are open specs that you can review. There's no option to password protect or encrypt the image contents in either. You would need to perform this protection either in your application or perform a decrypt as part of the entrypoint/command before your application is launched.